# Show multiple events at JTAppleCalendarView

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I am implementing JTAppleCalendarView in Swift. How I can show multiple events in Calendar without interaction at Calendar View i.e. Multiple events should be shown on Calendar.

Comment: What kind of events do you want to show?

Comment: @Jay : I am getting some date from server. All date should be show at Calendar as Event (ie. selected).

Comment: I have answered your question here -> https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/issues/45